# Error: __init__() keywords must be strings

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-filter

Django Filter is throwing an error when filtering by a many to many field. It appears that the predicate isn't being formed correctly as its formed as {None:[instance id]} I assume that it should be more like {id:[instance id]} 
Below is a copy of the relevant code on my end and the related error.

```
self.filters['template'] = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(
        choices=models.Template.objects.exclude(name__in=default_template_names).values_list('id', 'name'),
        widget=autocomplete.Select2Multiple(attrs={'data-placeholder': 'Template'}))
```

---

Error occurs here:

```
django_filters/filters.py in filter at line 248
            v = None
        predicate = self.get_filter_predicate(v)
        if self.conjoined:
            qs = self.get_method(qs)(**predicate)
        else:
            q |= Q(**predicate)
```

predicate is:

```
{None: '66'}
```

66 is the ID of the relevant instance trying to be filtered on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by correctly setting the field_name kwarg when creating the filter.

```
self.filters['template'] = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(
        field_name="template", # This is new!
        choices=models.Template.objects.exclude(name__in=default_template_names).values_list('id', 'name'),
        widget=autocomplete.Select2Multiple(attrs={'data-placeholder': 'Template'}))
```